# Intent ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED restarts app killing another running instance

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast

I'm creating a library that needs to receive the `Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED`. The library is initialized in the `onCreate` method of the  app activity that extends the application class.

After the boot event, when the boot event is completed, the app receives the broadcast and than starts normally processing stuff.

In some situations, my library needs to create some alarms. Depending of the SDK version I use the `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle`, `setExact`, and set methods of the `AlarmManager` class.

If I set one alarm and than turn the phone off (the alarm time at some is elapsed), when the boot the phone, the elapsed alarm starts my application. This starts a method and the library starts doing some stuff.

At some point, the app receives the `Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED`. At this point, the previous app is killed (and the library stops performing the tasks it was running) and a new app is created.
I can see this in the log messages in the process and thread id's field.

Here is an example of the logcat. `Init()` is called to by the application class to set up my library. After the boot intent is received, a new process is started.

```
10-31 17:13:57.545 3597-3597 D/App: Init() called
// does stuff
10-31 17:14:00.500 3597-3597 D/App: BootReceiver Boot broadcast received. Action =[android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED]
10-31 17:14:17.135 5243-5243 D/App: Init() called
// Restarts my library setup and tasks. Some of them are lost because they were started the the process triggered by the elapsed alarm.
```

How should I handle the alarm so that the process is not killed after the `BOOT_COMPLETED` event?

**EDIT**

```
11-01 16:27:44.774 1515-3949 I/ActivityManager: Start proc 4580:com.lib.test.app/u0a306 for broadcast com.lib.test.app/com.test.BootReceiver
....
11-01 16:27:50.194 1515-1621 I/ActivityManager: Killing 4580:com.lib.test.app/u0a306 (adj 906): empty #17
...
11-01 16:28:25.715 1515-5709 I/ActivityManager: Start proc 8413:com.test.app/u0a306 for broadcast com.lib.test.app/com.test.NetworkReceiver
```

Manifest receivers:

```
<receiver
            android:exported="true"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:name=".features.ping">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="PING"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:name=".features.boot.BootReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver
            android:enabled="true"
            android:name=".features.PackageReplaced">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver
            android:enabled="true"
            android:name=".features.PackageRemoved">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
            <data android:scheme="package"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver
            android:exported="false"
            android:name=".features.AlarmReceiver"/>

    <receiver
            android:name=".features.NetworkChangeReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!-- GCM Start-->
    <receiver
            android:name=".features.PushNotificationReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
            <category android:name="com.test.app"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver
            android:name=".features.SIMChangedReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: "the elapsed alarm starts my application" -- no, it does not, as registered `AlarmManager` events are cleared when a device is rebooted.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks. Did not knew that. Any idea why two process are being created?

Comment: It could be anything. Perhaps you are the home screen. Perhaps you have an active `AccessibilityService`. Perhaps you have an active `NotificationListenerService`. Perhaps you have an active implementation of the assist API and are the user's chosen assistant. And so forth. You know all the entry points into your app, as they are the components that you have registered in the manifest. Add logging to each to determine under what circumstances they get invoked.

Comment: Got many receivers on my manifest. Is it possible to put "something" in my application class so I can check what is responsible for my app starting?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, the `Application` class does not have any idea what is causing it to come into existence.

Comment: @CommonsWare I've got a bunch of receivers registered in my manifest and while debugging, after boot, it seams that when a receiver is notified, it kills the previous process of my app. As an example, after the app is started after receiving the boot completed event, since it is also registered to the connectivity change, after receiving the broadcast, my
process is killed and a new one is created Can this be de case? If so, can I register my receivers so that they do not start a new process if the app is already running? Modified original question.

Comment: "Can this be de case?" -- I would phrase it more as "once `onReceive()` returns, your process may be terminated". In particular, during periods of high process churn (e.g., running through all the `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` recipients), your process lifetime will be exceptionally short.